# Release fixes with only some changes from CVS trunk without using branches

Tags: cvs, release, release-management, production, branch

I have this kind of situation:

CVS trunk - all changes, stable ad unstable, are made to trunk.

production - major releases are made creating tags on CVS, but minor fixes are made manually, merging only the requested changes from trunk.

I'm not allowed to use branches, so I need an alternative solution to simplify or automate the process, because right now the risk of errors is too high.

Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: "Not allowed to use branches"? Sorry, but whoever made this rule is an idiot.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, that simple solution you're looking for - it's called branching.
Why are you not allowed to use branches? is it programmatically enforced?  That's you're problem, and it is solvable - hopefully by canning the guy who forbids you.

Comment: Prior experiences with branches have gone awry. That has probably been caused by lack of adeguate knowledge about what software configuration actually is and works (and that's imho the reason we are still using CVS, and no automated processes at all), but I have no power over that. All I can do is patch the actual situation and try to reduce risk, while trying to convince people over my in the hierarchy.

Comment: I feel your pain.  Perhaps a good point of attack in convincing those upstream would be to change to svn.  The migration is usually painless, and since it was designed to be a drop in replacement to CVS most of the staff will have no trouble.  SVN doesn't have the best branching and merging but it's lightyears ahead of CVS.  If the project is large, maybe showing the management how long it takes to tag in CVS and then explaining that it's near instant in SVN - regardless of the size of the codebase would be a good bit of 'magic' to show off.